# if statement in ONESHELL Makefile not working

Tags: makefile

I get `/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file` for the  if statement in the makefile below — what's wrong?  (My prompt is `/tmp >`.)

```
/tmp > make test
set -e
if [[ -f /tmp/device ]] ; then  
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [test] Error 2
/tmp > cat Makefile 
.ONESHELL:
test:   
    set -e
    if [[ -f /tmp/device ]] ; then  
    echo 'Do something' 
    fi
```

I am using GNU Make 3.81.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using GNU Make 3.81, the [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) feature is demonstrably not supported — you showed that, and I showed that. I tested on Mac OS X 10.11.5, with the supplied `/usr/bin/make` as GNU Make 3.81.  I demonstrated to my satisfaction by adding strategically placed `echo PID=$$$$` lines before `set -e`, after it, and so on, and observed different PID values. GNU Make version 3.81 is from 2006 (there was also version 3.82 from 2010, before version 4.x was released, starting with 4.0 in 2013).

The current version of GNU Make is 4.2.1 (June 2016).  That version does support the feature; your script works as expected when using a sufficiently recent version of GNU Make.  It is a feature that has been around for a while — you probably don't have to upgrade to the latest to get the support, but why would you go with a down-version if you're going to upgrade anyway.

If you wish to use the `.ONSHELL:` feature, you'll have to ensure you are using a new enough version of GNU Make (newer than version 3.81). If that's not feasible, don't use the feature.

---

Reading the NEWS file from 4.2.1, it is clear that `ONESHELL` was added to GNU Make version 3.82:

> ```
> Version 3.82 (28 Jul 2010)
>
> …
>
> * New special target: .ONESHELL instructs make to invoke a single instance
>   of the shell and provide it with the entire recipe, regardless of how many
>   lines it contains.  As a special feature to allow more straightforward
>   conversion of makefiles to use .ONESHELL, any recipe line control
>   characters ('@', '+', or '-') will be removed from the second and
>   subsequent recipe lines.  This happens _only_ if the SHELL value is deemed
>   to be a standard POSIX-style shell.  If not, then no interior line control
>   characters are removed (as they may be part of the scripting language used
>   with the alternate SHELL).
> ```

Comment: Jonathan 3.81 has ONESHELL just not the 'if' condition and such I guess. becuase echo and other bash commands seem to work.

Comment: @Victor: I'm not sure what you mean.  Using ONESHELL means that all the actions for a recipe are executed in a single shell, regardless of how many lines are used.  In the example, the `set` and the three lines of `if`/`then`/`else are all run in a single shell.  The release notes (NEWS file) make it clear that ONESHELL was added to 3.82 and was not in 3.81.  If you have a variant of GNU Make claiming to be 3.81 but with ONESHELL support, it is not a version released by GNU, AFAICT.  Maybe a distro back-ported the feature for some reason, instead of releasing 3.82.

Comment: Note too that the `if` that is failing is pure shell code; it is not a GNU Make conditional.